# Create a Button with a Large Icon

Tags: python, add-on, development

How would I add a button with a large icon in the Blender interface in my menu for an addon?
I figured out how to make a button with a small icon on the left side, but if I want an image to be the majority of the button space, how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you modeling a large button mesh?  Are you referring to the Blender interface?

Comment: Editing my question to clarify!

Comment: Are you certain that feature exists in Blender python api? I've check the interface and some of my addons and cannot find any *large* buttons. Maybe there aren't any other button styles.

Comment: Maybe the feature doesn't exist :-/.  In which case it sounds like I have a hell of a programming task ahead of me.  I'd be really, really surprised though if in all of Blender's years nobody has wanted to create a button with a larger icon.